DIfference between どういう訳も and なぜという訳も
From Kokoro chapter 25:

「先生はなぜ元のように書物に興味をもち得ないんですか」
「なぜという訳もありませんが。……つまりいくら本を読んでもそれほどえらくならないと思うせいでしょう。それから……」

I found the use of なぜ in なぜという訳もありません odd to me. I'd understand its meaning if it were written as どういう訳もありません ("there is no particular reason") instead. Is there any difference between どういう訳も and なぜという訳も?

I think it echoes the なぜ that was used in the question,「先生はなぜ…」

This expression is unfamiliar to me, too, and どうという訳もありません is much more common (どういう訳もありません is incorrect).
Here, I think なぜという訳もありません is essentially saying "I have no logic in response to your asking 'why'", or "There's no particular reason that warrants your asking why". A similar but more common expression is なぜという程でもありません (It's not really worth asking why → There is no big reason).
